# How to split up sails.js controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I was thinking to achieve this by splitting the long controller actions into single modules, but how can I do this without affecting the Blueprint API?

Comment: One in-framework way to add reusable code and thin out your controllers appears to be services: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/services/creating-a-service. I don't quite understand how extracting code into modules or services would affect Blueprints. Maybe explain what you are trying to do in a little more detail?

Answer (score 1):

I used services for this purpose. And then I called them from controller. 
Here is some [source code](https://github.com/AlexanderKozhevin/sport-api/tree/master/api).